# Is it safe to init `StringRef` with a string literal?

Tags: llvm

I'm new to LLVM and this might be a silly question.

`StringRef` is ubiquitously used in the LLVM codebase. It doesn't own the string data and the lifetime of the string data should extend that of the `StringRef`.

I'm wondering that in the following example when a string literal is used for initializing a `StringRef`, what's the lifetime of that `""` literal, and how can I guarantee that its lifetime extends that of the `StringRef`.

```
static std::unique_ptr<MemoryBuffer>
  getMemBuffer(StringRef InputData, StringRef BufferName = "",
               bool RequiresNullTerminator = true);
```

I guess string interning may happen here but that is probably compiler-dependent.

Comment: A string literal exists until the end of time — it is in the executable file itself, constructed before runtime starts.